# In C# can you perform a Range Select within a Range Select?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I ultimately want to get every date for the current year in a List.

I have the following which gives me all dates for a given month..

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            List<DateTime> ldtDates = new List<DateTime>();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int intCurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int intCurrentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

            List<DateTime> DatesThisMonth =
                Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(intCurrentYear, intCurrentMonth))
                          .Select(i => new DateTime(intCurrentYear, intCurrentMonth, i))
                          .ToList();

            foreach (var q in DatesThisMonth)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

This works for the month, however I want to wrap a Range(1,12) around this code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        List<DateTime> ldtDates = new List<DateTime>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int intCurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        int intCurrentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

        var DatesThisYesr =
            Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(y=>
            Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(intCurrentYear, y))
                      .Select(i => new DateTime(intCurrentYear, intCurrentMonth, i))
                      ).ToList();

        foreach (var q in DatesThisYesr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(q);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here is what my output looks like:

```
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.DateT
ime]
Press <enter> to continue
```

I could use a For loop, however it should be possible to do this via Linq.

Thanks,

Comment: You show what you tried, great! But you don't tell why it fails (apparently).

Comment: Thanks, I just added the output from my failed attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` like this:

```
var DatesThisYesr =
    Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    .SelectMany(month =>
        Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(intCurrentYear, month))
        .Select(day => new DateTime(intCurrentYear, month, day)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're currently selecting a sequence of sequences - which is why when you print each element out, it's showing that it's a `WhereSelectEnumeratableIterator`. I suspect you *actually* want to just flatten that, so you should use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`. Note that you *don't* want to use `intCurrentMonth` though - you want to use `y` (which is an odd name for a variable which effectively represents a *month* number).

It would probably be simpler to write this as a query expression though:

```
var dates = from month in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            from day in Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
            select new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

I don't see any reason to call `ToList()` here, given that you're just iterating over the result. Note how the use of meaningful range variable names makes the whole thing *much* more readable.